# How do I create .so files with all libraries statically linked into it?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, static-linking, protobuf-c

I want to create a .so file with all libraries (GMP and PROTOBUF) statically linked into it so that it can be used in other systems without installing those libraries.

This is what I did for MAC:

```
gcc -I /usr/local/include -shared -o xyz.so -g xyz.c /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.a /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
```

But it doesn't work for Linux. How can I make it work for Linux?

Answer (score 2):

A shared [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) should (on Linux) practically contain [**position-independent code**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (PIC). So the correct way to build a shared library `libxyz.so` out of a *single* source file `xyz.c` is

```
gcc -Wall -g -shared -I/usr/local/include -o libxyz.so -fPIC xyz.c
```

(and you could -and probably want to- add [*rpath*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) related options)

A static library don't contain PIC (unless it was *specially* built as such, which is very uncommon on Linux ; on Debian the only example I know is the special `libc6-pic` package provided to facilitate build of customized and extended `libc*so`).

You need to link PIC variants of these libraries; so you should build them from their source code.

Read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) for more, and also [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

<sup>(In *some few* theoretical *weird* cases, you could link a shared library which don't contain PIC, but that will make their [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) extremely slow, since a lot of [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) would be processed and their [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) won't be shared -between several processes- by appropriate calls to [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) done by [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html); this is *not recommended* at all, is very brittle, and often won't work well; I never did that)</sup>

> I want to create a .so file with all libraries (GMP and PROTOBUF) statically linked into it

**Don't do that**. I explained why. And doing that is against the (social) rules on Linux (because your users don't want to have zillions of variants of libgmp, etc...).

You can however link a shared library with some previous other (more basic) shared libraries. In your case, I recommend doing that. So require your user to have installed GMP and PROTOBUF packages.

Consider also providing [packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for your (or common) Linux distributions (e.g. a [`.deb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) file for Ubuntu or Debian)

Alternatively, publish your library code as [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software); you might then hope that several users would download its source, and perhaps (eventually) some distribution would package it. You could wait years for that to happen; or at least you get help to package it.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I understand that I must not use static files. I instead tried runtime search path like this: gcc -Wall -g -shared -I/usr/local/include -o module.so -fPIC module.c -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/libprotoc.so  . After this, module.so got created successfully. But when the module is loaded, it stops loading and says "undefined symbol: protobuf_c_message_pack". So that means, the library is not searched at my rpath location right? Note: I don't need GMP for this .so creation. It doesn't use GMP

Comment: I strongly recommend spending one day reading Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). You need the knowledge there.

Comment: Okay I will do that ASAP